# Is there a way to print out the bean id of each bean spring creates

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm reading in a number of xml files which have bean definitions in them. I want to see the bean id of each bean as spring starts the process of reading the XML and/or creating the bean.

I have bean definition files, and I'm not certain they are being read in.  I'd like to be certain.

Answer (score 3):

If you have log4j turned on, all the app contexts and their bean names will be printed to the console/log.